# Laravel web login using token

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem

how to login to laraver without login from different website

so i have 2 website laravel and php native

when user login to php native and user open the laravel user does not need to login again.
this use different database.

my plan :

1 user login in php native and login to laravel via API to get token

2 when user open the laravel user send the token to web route, but i'm not found any tutorials for login laravel web using token

if you have another better way, please tell me

thanks